# Bot Mentions Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
  if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
    await ctx.send("Hi!")
```

So I want my bot to respond to anyone who @mentions it. It does work as it should, but the only problem it'll respond to @everyone and @here pings. It's probably simple and I am overthinking it but I just want to know if there is any way to make the bot respond to messages it's actually mentioned in, not @everyone or @here pings?

Comment: @meph That doesn't rlly do anything tho. The bot will still respond to @ everyone and @ here. I don't think my question was clear enough but thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn't read it properly. I'll delete that non sense. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the bot's user id is in the message content. Try the following:

```py
    if str(client.user.id) in message.content:
        await ctx.send("Hi!")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Hmm Try This

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if f"<@!{client.user.id}>" in message.content:
    await ctx.send("Hi!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
```

Then detect if the message has mentioned the bot:

```
if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
    await message.channel.send("Hi!")
```

Documentation: https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=mentioned#discord.ClientUser.mentioned_in

Answer (score 0):

In discord.py 1.7.3 the following code works

```
if client.user in message.mentions:
    await message.channel.send("Hi!")
```